# What is a good way to call a method from the main game loop via a scheduled alarm?

Tags: android, android-service, libgdx, android-alarms

I'm using libgdx for a game, and I want to be able to have the game call an `update()` method that is set up right now to get called every 15 minutes. However, this only works of course when the game itself is open, and I want this to work as long as the device is on.

So far I figured out how to create the BroadcastReceiver and use AlarmManager to call it every 15 minutes, and I know how to set it up to add my alarm in on boot. The only thing I have to figure out is how to have that scheduled on exact 15 minute intervals(i.e. 9:30,9:45, etc.)

This is the source for the AndroidApplication:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java

And the code used to start it is like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = true;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    initialize(new MainClass(), cfg);
}
```

Looking around can't see to find any way of actually referencing the `MainClass()` without calling `onCreate()`. I'm assuming the best way to do something like this have a separate intent with a copy of the `update()` method and access to the same data be called instead, however I don't know how to do that in libgdx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make your game class do too much, not to mention this will run into problems when you're "alarm" fires and the game is not running so nothing could receive the call to update(). If what you really need is a way to periodically update some data for your game outside of your running game loop I would approach it like so:

1. Create your AlarmManager as you have, but instead of trying to reach into your existing game class and call update, just store of the updates to a SharedStorage location. [{Android Docs}](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
2. Create a new Interface in your core project that defines a StoredDataReader.
3. Create a new class in your android project called AndroidStoredDataReader that implements StoredDataReader, and knows how to read from the stored updates location.
4. Overload your MainClass() constructor to take in a "StoredDataReader" instance.
5. In your onCreate() method, you then build up your AndroidStoredDataReader class, and then pass that to your new MainClass() call.
6. In your game's update/render loop you would then ask the StoredDataReader for the required data.

This would allow you to also take the same approach if you port the application to GWT or desktop, where you can implement the StoredDataReader for each platform.  (GWTStoredData reader might read from the browser localStorage, the desktop version might read from a local file, etc)